# Trying to get authorization token from url works in browser, but not in WebRequest

Tags: c#, webrequest

I'm working on setting up an authorized restful request and I'm having a hell of a time getting a valid response back. If I paste the request URL into a browser(Firefox Quantum and Chrome) I can get a response of Status:Authenticated;token:[token string] but when I try WebRequest.Create([url]) I keep getting a response of "400: bad request". I'm copying the URL straight from debug code so I know it's valid. I'm pretty sure I'm doing something simple wrong. Would someone point me in the right direction?

```
            string loginReq = _authPath + "?user=" + _username + "&pw=" + _password;
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(loginReq);
        request.Accept = "text/html, application/xhtml + xml, */*";
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0(Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv: 11.0) like Gecko";
        request.KeepAlive = true;



        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        Console.WriteLine(response.ResponseUri);

        Console.Read();
```

Ok, after doing some more poking it looks like the site I'm calling is refusing the request because it thinks I'm using IE9. Here's the latest version of the code
            private static string GetAuthorization() {
            string token = string.Empty;

```
        string loginReq =  _authPath + "?user=" + _ftpUsername + "&pw=" + _ftpPassword;

        string task = SendWebRequest(loginReq);
            //HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(loginReq);
            //request.Accept = "text/html, application/xhtml + xml, */*";
            //request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0(Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv: 11.0) like Gecko";
            //request.KeepAlive = true;
            //request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
            //request.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            //request.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US");
            //request.Headers.Add("DNT", "1");
            //request.Method = "GET";
            //request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            //request.Headers.Add("Request", "GET /xc2/QAPI_Upload?user=user@ottrtest1.com&pw=ETqDJeQ1! HTTP/1.1");


            //HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            Console.WriteLine(task);

        Console.Read();

        return token;
    }

    public static string SendWebRequest(string requestUrl) {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(requestUrl).GetAwaiter().GetResult())
            return response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
```

I keep trying different things but I'm getting the same results(400 Bad Request) Here's the latest version of what I'm working with

```
        string loginReq = $"{_authPath}?user={_userName}&pw={_passWord}";
        string result;
        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient()) {
            var json = wc.DownloadString(loginReq);
            result = json.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(json);
        }
```

If I change the url to "https://www.google.com" my code works. if I paste loginReq into SoapUI it works, I can't get the url and my code to work together...

---

Fiddler found the problem. Once I reviewed the request in fiddler I saw that I needed to set the security protocol type to tls1.0, tls1.1, or tls1.2. Once I did that I finally got the call to work. Here's the working code in case anyone needs it for reference:

```
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)192 | (SecurityProtocolType)768 | (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
        string loginReq = $"{_authPath}?user={_userName}&pw={_passWord}";
        string result;
        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient()) {
            var json = wc.DownloadString(loginReq);
            result = json.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(json);
        }


        return result;
```

Comment: Which protocol? Any sample URL? Please add more info, we can't guess what you're doing.

Comment: I'm sending a Https request in the format of "https://site.address?user=[username]&pw=[password].

Comment: What kind of request? Please show your code.

Comment: If your problem is what you think it is then add a User-Agent header.

Comment: I tried that with no luck.

Comment: Compare the request made in the browser with the request via C# using fiddler. After you find the difference, adapt the code to mimic the browser request (headers, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Fiddler found the problem. Once I reviewed the request in fiddler I saw that I needed to set the security protocol type to tls1.0, tls1.1, or tls1.2. Once I did that I finally got the call to work. Here's the working code in case anyone needs it for reference:

```
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)192 | (SecurityProtocolType)768 | (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
    string loginReq = $"{_authPath}?user={_userName}&pw={_passWord}";
    string result;
    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient()) {
        var json = wc.DownloadString(loginReq);
        result = json.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(json);
    }


    return result;
```

Comment: 400 Bad Request is an odd response for a TLS issue.

Comment: that's what fixed it, I also found out that the target server is using Salesforce. I don't know if that's why I was seeing the odd error message, All I know is it works now.